# Concise scheme R5RS define struct or class with multiple fields

Tags: scheme, racket, r5rs

I've managed to define a struct with one field, how to define multiple fields in one struct or class?

I'm new to R5RS, I can only come up with problematic code, please see it as pseudo code expressing what I'm trying to do.

```
(define recipe 
    (let (salt 5)
         (sauce "ketchup")))
```

or

```
(define recipe
   '((let salt 5)
     (let sauce "ketchup")))
```

What's the most concise and common way(s) to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most Scheme implementations provide records via [SRFI 9](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-9/srfi-9.html). So in your case, you can define a `recipe` record type like so:

```
(define-record-type <recipe>
  (recipe salt sauce)
  recipe?
  (salt recipe-salt)
  (sauce recipe-sauce))
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
> (define salty-ketchup (recipe 5 "ketchup"))
> (recipe-salt salty-ketchup)
5
> (recipe-sauce salty-ketchup)
"ketchup"
```

---

If you're using Racket, there's an even simpler syntax for defining structs.

```
(struct recipe (salt sauce))
```